# I have a table of calls data I want to figure out the count Unique accounts called everyday and take sum of unique accounts called by monthly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 unique columns one has an account number and the other is the date. The sample data is given below.

```
Date    account
9/8/2020    555
9/8/2020    666
9/8/2020    777
9/8/2020    888
9/9/2020    555
9/9/2020    999
9/10/2020   555
9/10/2020   222
9/10/2020   333
9/11/2020   666
9/11/2020   111
```

I would like to calculate the number of unique accounts called every day and sum it up for a month for example if account number 555 is called on 8sept, p sept and 20 Sept its is not adding up to the cumulative sum the result should look like this

```
date    Cumulative Unique Accounts Called SO Far this month
9/8/2020    4
9/9/2020    5
9/10/2020   7
9/11/2020   8
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Every day, even weekends?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation and window functions.  First, get the first date for each account, then aggregate and accumulate:

```
select min_date,
       count(*) as as_of_date,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by year(min_datedate), month(min_datedate)
                           order by min_date
                          ) as cumulative_unique_count
from (select account, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by account, year(date), month(date)
     ) t
group by min_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
with cte as
(
select date,count(*) as total from
(
select date,count,row_number() over(partition by count order by date) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1 group by date
)

select date,sum(total) over(order by date) as cum_sum
from cte
```